# Why Eclipse does not show the output but Windows CMD does?

Tags: java, eclipse

Running the following code when the `int[] array` length is 10000 doesn't show output in Eclipse, if I use the windows CMD, the output is printed. When the array length is 1000 Eclipse also prints the output. So why doesn't eclipse print the output for large data?

```
package sorting;

import java.util.Random;

public class InsertionSort {
    public static int[] insertionSortAlgorithm(int[] array){
        for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++){
            int key = array[i] ;
            int j = i-1 ;
            while(j>=0 && array[j]>key){
                array[j+1] = array[j] ;
                j-- ;
            }
            array[j+1] = key ;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random rand = new Random(25) ;
        int[] array = new int[10000] ;
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            array[i] = rand.nextInt(100) ;
        }
        for(int i : array){
            System.out.print(i + " ") ;
        }
        int[] array2 = insertionSortAlgorithm(array) ;
        System.out.println() ;
        for(int i : array2){
            System.out.print(i + " ") ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Eclipse doesn't run the algorithm"? Is there an exception thrown? If so, please include the stack trace.

Comment: Is it 10,000 or 100,000? What do you mean "input", I see no input in your code. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, My input is "new int[10000]",that i want to sort the 10000 integer,but Eclipse doesn't throw exception and doesn't run (actually it run one second and end ),when i change 10000 to 1000 the i can output the excepted results,why?

Comment: What did you find when you ran the code in your debugger?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the output console doesn't handle well very long lines. Just to show it, change the `print` in

```
for(int i : array2){
    System.out.print(i + " ") ;
}
```

to `println` and everything will show. The program runs anyhow.

To fix this, go to *Windows --> Preferences  --> Run/Debug --> Console* and select *Fixed width console*. Choose a value like 1000.

Comment: @冯孟昭 Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.